# Non-AngularJS form submitting to AngularJS app - URL needs rewriting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite

I have an AngularJS search app, however the search box itself resides in a (non-angularJS) standard html page. The input looks like:

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="search" id="search" action="/search/app/#/results" method="get" >
  <legend class="title">Search everything!</legend>
  <input type="text" class="styledTextInput" name="q" placeholder="Keywords" />
  <button class="btn btn-search" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, The URL appears as:

```
myapp.com/search/app/?q=medical#/results
```

For It to work properly, I need the URL to be:

```
myapp.com/search/app/#/results?q=medical
```

I have tried various ways of getting Apache to rewrite the URL but have not been successful (not really my forte). Is it the webserver or AngularJS that I need to look at to solve this? All the examples I've found assume that the form is in AngularJS (in my case, making the search box part of the AngularJS app is not an option)

Comment: What about using Jquery to intercept the form submit, change the URL according to the input and do a manual submit?

Comment: Thanks @Lucas ! I should have thought of that! Using jQuery to reset the action attribute on the form did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full method I used was as follows:

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.btn-search').click( function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var q = $(".styledTextInput").val();
           $("#search").attr("action", "/search/app/#/results?q=" + q).submit();
     });
});
</script>
```